# How to execute while loop given number of times?

Tags: c#, winforms, while-loop

I have this while loop to get next working day excluding holidays and sundays.
But it calculates by adding 1 day. And i want that number of day to be given by the user. I get that input from the below *TextBox* (TboxIzin).

How can execute that while loop to do the calculation for given number of times?

```
         int i = 1;
         int sayi;
         IzinIslem i1 = new IzinIslem();
         int.TryParse(i1.TboxIzin.Text, out sayi);
```

```
            public static DateTime GetNextWeekDay(DateTime date, 
                 IList<Holiday> holidays, IList<DayOfWeek> weekendDays)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int sayi;
            IzinIslem i1 = new IzinIslem();
            int.TryParse(i1.TboxIzin.Text, out sayi);

            // always start with tomorrow, and truncate time to be safe
            date = date.Date.AddDays(1);

            // calculate holidays for both this year and next year
            var holidayDates = holidays.Select(x => x.GetDate(date.Year))
                .Union(holidays.Select(x => x.GetDate(date.Year + 1)))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            // increment to get working day
            while (true)
            {
                if (weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) || 
                          holidayDates.Contains(date))
                    date = date.AddDays(1);
                else
                    return date;
            }

        }
```

I get `not all code paths return a value`
 error when i try nesting while loops.

Comment: Consider using `for` rather than `while`. And make sure there is a `return` **after** the `for` / `while`.

Comment: `for (; weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) || holidayDates.Contains(date); date = date.AddDays(1));`  then `return date;`

Comment: the error is because you don't include a return statement after the while loop.  It may look like this is a place that never gets executed but it could (say in the case of an exception.

Comment: If you can calculate the number of repetitions in advance, use `for`. If you don't know how many it'll be, use `while`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko and how should i handle the input?. In my code, i=count, sayi=input number from textbox.

Comment: @Mert: but you don't use them (`i`, `sayi` etc.) in the `GetNextWeekDay`

Comment: in your while, check if the day is a week day and not a holiday and then break out of loop.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko But in my GetNextWeekDay method the input is 1 and it gets the staring date via DateTimePicker. So every time it gets the same date and returns he same value. How can i change that?

Comment: @Mert: I can't see any `DateTimePicker` within the method but `GetNextWeekDay(DateTime date...` and then `date = date.Date.AddDays(1);`. 
Sure, you can *call* the method with an argument from `DateTimePicker` like `var MyDate =  GetNextWeekDay(myDateTimePicker.Value, ...);` 
but it's another story.

Answer (score 5):

while is a conditional loop. Here you put a non-condition in the clause and immediately follow up with a condition. Put the condition in the while clause:

```
while(weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) || holidayDates.Contains(date)) {
    date = date.AddDays(1);
}

return date;
```

The actual reason you're getting the error is that the compiler cannot predict if your if condition will ever resolve to false. If it doesn't, then your function never returns.

With the modified while loop, that may still happen, but it will result in an infinite loop, and the compiler is fine if you shoot yourself in the foot that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `else` clause to break out of the loop. And then return out of the loop.

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (weekendDays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek) || 
                      holidayDates.Contains(date))
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            else
                break;
        }
        return date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's get rif of all UI in the `GetNextWeekDay` (like `int.TryParse(i1.TboxIzin.Text, out sayi);`):

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekDay(DateTime date, 
                                      IEnumerable<Holiday> holidays, 
                                      IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> weekendDays) {

  // public method arguments validation
  if (null == holidays)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(holidays));
  else if (null == weekendDays)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(weekendDays));

  HashSet<DayOfWeek> wends = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>(weekendDays);

  // Current Year and Next years - .AddYear(1)
  HashSet<DateTime> hds = new HashSet<DateTime>(holidays
    .Select(item => item.Date)
    .Concate(holidays.Select(item => item.Date.AddYear(1))));  

  for (var day = date.Date.AddDays(1); ; day = day.AddDays(1)) 
    if (!wends.Contains(day.DayOfWeek) && ! hds.Contains(day))
      return day;
}
```

Or if you prefer *Linq*, the loop can be rewritten as

```
return Enumerable
  .Range(1, 1000)
  .Select(day => date.Date.AddDays(day))
  .TakeWhile(item => item.Year - date.Year <= 1)
  .First(item => !wends.Contains(item.DayOfWeek) && !hds.Contains(item));
```